# Create key with objectify

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Calling Objectify method:

  `Key.create(ParentClass.class parentClass, KindClass.class kindClass,  String id)`

for the exactly same parameters twice at the same time, I got: 

  `name=UWxoCs7KpxDu2fYBI3s2fkOq-wM 
  name=jOqQzhZzAScJ0O3OEtYF3jzb34Q`

Does this method need to run in a transaction so I get a predictable result?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app id and namespace are also encoded in the key. You can see the components that represent a stable key here:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.java

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any reference to an Objectify `Key.createKey` method. Which version of Objectify are you using?

There is however a `Key.create(Key<?> parent, java.lang.Class<? extends T> kindClass, java.lang.String name)`, trying using that and let us know how you get on.

Here is the API page for `Key` https://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html

Comment: But note that the function that @elcid shows specifies the parent entity explicitly, not just the parent class.

Comment: This question is all based on mistake - written in a hurry. Cant cancel it;)